# Ruby with RailsInstaller, can't build gem native extensions on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, devkit

After installing Ruby + Rails on Windows with RailsInstaller, i couldn't install any gems that required to build native extensions. Error:

```
C:\Users\Admin>gem install rdiscount
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rdiscount:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/r
discount-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdiscount-1.6.8/ex
t/gem_make.out
```

Content of gem_make.out:

```
C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

I already went through [this troubleshooting page](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-gems_fails_comspec_autorun), but it didn't fix this error.
It seems that Ruby can't spawn child processes, because when i run extconf.rb manually, it works.

PATH:

```
C:\Rails\DevKit\bin;C:\Rails\DevKit\mingw\bin;C:\Rails\Git\cmd;C:\Rails\Ruby1.9.2\bin;C:\Program Files\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: What is the values of COMSPEC and the registry, as suggested in the troubleshooting page? Please update the question with that and also what version of Windows you're using.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/87283/how-to-install-rdiscount-ruby-gem-in-windows-vista

Comment: Did you install the [development kit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit) for windows ? And also please read section 4. of the above link on how to properly make it work

Comment: There is some information on this page : http://www.jeffcohenonline.com/installing-rails . You will need the DevKit before building any gem native extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a really compelling reason to run natively on Windows, I would install [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) and just run Ubuntu or your favorite flavor of Linux for Rails development. Things will end up working a lot more smoothly.